# Is there an alternative to SIMION?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, simulations, software

Is anyone aware of an alternative, possibly open-source, to the SIMION software?

From their website:

> SIMION is a particle optics simulation software primarily used to
>   calculate electric fields and the trajectories of charged particles in
>   those fields when given a configuration of electrodes with voltages
>   and particle initial conditions, including optional RF (quasistatic),
>   magnetic field, and collisional effects.

One of the main advantages when using SIMION is that one can directly import a CAD drawing via the STL format, but SIMION is old, really old - the last update is from 6 years ago. Also, it is not available for Linux.

We use SIMION in our group to simulate time-of-flight spectra and were wondering if there is an alternative. I was unable to find anything useful on the google and wanted to ask fellow physicists who may have the same problems.

Comment: And you should check out https://simion.com/info/linux.html for information on running SIMION under Linux - it does work.